# PIC18 with ACT HC49/US XTAL

Tags: microcontroller, pic, resistors, oscillator, crystal

As part of my current project I need to ensure that my MCU (namely `PIC18F4520`) runs smoothly, minimizing the possibility of any interruptions. The [datasheet](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fww1.microchip.com%2Fdownloads%2Fen%2Fdevicedoc%2F39631e.pdf&ei=qR0IUYGMKoqm0AXzjYGoAg&usg=AFQjCNFyofJLjtujYah4FAKTYn7hhRBn4A&sig2=JX7zc7i1-hHdryrXylzeFA&bvm=bv.41524429,d.d2k) specifies that a series resistor, `Rs` of value `330 ohms`, should be used for AT strip-cut crystals.

[image: OSC input]

> A series resistor (RS) may be required for AT
>   strip cut crystals.
>
> If HS is
>   selected, it is possible that the gain of the
>   oscillator will overdrive the resonator.
>   Therefore, a series resistor should be
>   placed between the OSC2 pin and the
>   resonator. As a good starting point, the
>   recommended value of RS is 330Ω.

By my understanding, AT strip cut crystals can be (generally) identified by [square shape](http://www.foxonline.com/techfaqs.htm#a24). I'm using [ACT HC49/US](http://www.actcrystals.com/_files/franchise/Advanced_Crystal_Technology/datasheets/ACT_HC49US_Custom.pdf). The datasheet, sadly, does not answer whether the crystal is AT strip cut or not. Hence my question: is it? And is 330 ohms a suitable value to be used?

Comment: Ask the crystal manufacturer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up several things.  You state that the datasheet says a resistor should be used, but even the section you quote only says "may be required" for some crystals.  Then they go on to talk about overdriving *resonators*, not crystals.

Basically, I wouldn't worry about it.  Use the lowest power oscillator setting that results in reliable operation.  If you do that, you're quite unlikely to overdrive a ordinary crystal.  Take a look at the output of the crystal on a scope, but remember to use a high impedance scope probe.  A "1x" (usually 1 MΩ) can kill the signal. Use "10x" or 10 MΩ at least.  If the resulting sine wave on the ouput of the crystal is nearly the full supply range, then you probably want the next lower power setting.  Up to about half the supply range peak to peak should be fine for ordinary crystals.

No, you can't tell the crystal "cut" from the can shape.  Sometimes the datasheet mentions this, sometimes it doesn't.  It is probably better if you don't think you know something about the crystal based on its supposed cut type anyway.  The important spec is the power level it can operate at.  Physically bigger crystals will work at higher power levels.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I misread the datasheet and was under the impression that they are referring to the crystal as 'resonator', reading that again now doesn't make much sense, as you said. Thanks for the advice on how to experimentally determine if the crystal is being under overdrive - I will check it in the lab tomorrow.

Comment: A crystal is a resonator. There are ceramic resonators, of course, but they aren't relevant in  your case. They could be overdriven, as well.

Comment: @Leon: In this context I think it is quite clear that a "resonator" refers to a ceramic resonator, which is definitely not a "crystal", meaning a quartz crystal.  So no, a "crystal" is not a "resonator" in the context used here.

Comment: They are clearly referring to a crystal resonator, as shown in the diagram.